# Multiple Window Events - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to write a function that watches the window for a few things:

1. If the window is greater-than `900px` and the window is scrolled passed `100` add a BG color to the nav
2. If the `nav` is scrolled passed `100` and the window is resized to less-than `900px` change the BG color nav.

I've written two functions that should be doing the trick. My problem is my functions work right up until you scroll passed `100` and resize the screen: they won't apply the second class with the second bg color.

Snippet below.  Can anyone provide assistance?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var nav = $('nav');
  
  if( scroll > 100 ) {
   nav.addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
   nav.removeClass('scrolled');
  }
 });
 
 
 
 $(window).resize(function() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 900px)');
  
  if( mq.matches && $('nav').hasClass('scrolled')) {
   $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
   console.log("Working");
   $('nav').addClass('scrolledTwo');
  } else {
   console.log("Not working");
   $('nav').removeClass('scrolledTwo');
  }
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav {
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-fixedWidth {
 height: inherit;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 2000px;
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}



.scrolled {
 background-color: red;
}

.scrolledTwo {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div class="nav-fixedWidth"></div>
</nav>

<main></main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine it is even applying the second class with the second bg color if you will resize slowly your window. The only issue is this `if( mq.matches && $('nav').hasClass('scrolled'))` condition. As you have mentioned `$('nav').hasClass('scrolled')` so first time when you will resize it will be true and then

```
$('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
console.log("Working");
$('nav').addClass('scrolledTwo');
```

this will apply `scrolledTwo` class to nav. After that when you will further resize it will never pass this `if( mq.matches && $('nav').hasClass('scrolled'))` condition, until you don't resize the screen width to less than 100px or greater than 900px and scroll, and will always goto else and you will always see the red color. Try removing it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var nav = $('nav');
  
  if( scroll > 100 ) {
   nav.addClass('scrolled');
  } else {
   nav.removeClass('scrolled');
  }
 });
 
 
 
 $(window).resize(function() {
  var mq = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 900px)');
  
  if( mq.matches ) {
   $('nav').removeClass('scrolled');
   console.log("Working");
   $('nav').addClass('scrolledTwo');
  } else {
   console.log("Not working");
   $('nav').removeClass('scrolledTwo');
  }
 });
 
 
});
```

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

nav {
 height: 70px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid;
 transition: all .2s ease;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-fixedWidth {
 height: inherit;
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

main {
 width: 100%;
 height: 2000px;
 border: 1px solid;
 background-color: #f1f1f1;
}



.scrolled {
 background-color: red;
}

.scrolledTwo {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
 <div class="nav-fixedWidth"></div>
</nav>

<main></main>
```

Another issue in your code is if I scroll and resize the screen width between 100 to 900 and then again resize it to out of this window then there is no class assigned to your div and that is due to no  class added in else of resize function. Changing that to this will do that trick also :)

```
else {
        console.log("Not working");
        $('nav').removeClass('scrolledTwo');
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
       if( scroll > 100 ) {
         $('nav').addClass('scrolled');
       }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I just updated it please go through that also and your welcome

Comment: Can I ask you one further question?

Comment: @TheodoreSteiner  Yes

Comment: Oh you're latest update just answered it for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: yeah you can just put up that condition

Comment: I have one more question. Would you mind joining me in chat?